# How to intrepret some of the statements in Android.mk file

Tags: makefile, kernel, android-source

I have a Android.mk file which belongs to AOSP. There is a particular statement in this file:

```
$(TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG): $(KERNEL_CONFIG_FILE) $(LOCAL_PATH)/Android.mk
```

Can anyone explain what is this particular lines tells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `$(TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG)` will be rebuilt when `$(KERNEL_CONFIG_FILE)` changes, or when the **Android.mk** (that very file you are reading) changes.

Comment: is there any documentation to understand these kind of statements

Comment: Assuming it's GNU make you can find the docs [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).